# Hosts can't ping when ICMPv4 flow has been made

Tags: openwrt, sdn, opendaylight, openflow, openvswitch

I'm using OpenDayLight to be OpenFlow controller, i have 2 hosts that connect to the OpenFlow-enabled router (wr1043ndv4), the controller works fine to see the topology inventory, but when i want to try ping from one host to another i can't. i already made the flow according to the ICMPv4 guide

According to some post in here, the subnet mask for the destination address must /32, so i put the flow and it's in the flow table but the hosts can't ping to one another, i even try to make the subnet mask on the host to /32 to match what i put in the flow but still didn't work.

here my xml code that i changed a bit from the guide site:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<flow xmlns="urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory">
    <strict>false</strict>
    <instructions>
        <instruction>
            <order>0</order>
            <apply-actions>
                <action>
                    <order>0</order>
                    <dec-nw-ttl/>
                </action>
            </apply-actions>
        </instruction>
    </instructions>
    <table_id>235</table_id>
    <id>100</id>
    <cookie_mask>255</cookie_mask>
    <match>
        <ethernet-match>
            <ethernet-type>
                <type>2048</type>
            </ethernet-type>
            <ethernet-destination>
                <address>e8:06:88:xx:xx:xx</address>
            </ethernet-destination>
            <ethernet-source>
                <address>e8:06:88:xx:xx:xx</address>
            </ethernet-source>
        </ethernet-match>
        <ipv4-source>192.168.1.100/32</ipv4-source>
        <ipv4-destination>192.168.5.100/32</ipv4-destination>
        <ip-match>
            <ip-protocol>1</ip-protocol>
            <ip-dscp>27</ip-dscp>
            <ip-ecn>3</ip-ecn>
        </ip-match>
        <icmpv4-match>
            <icmpv4-type>6</icmpv4-type>
            <icmpv4-code>3</icmpv4-code>
        </icmpv4-match>
        <in-port>3</in-port>
    </match>
    <hard-timeout>1200</hard-timeout>
    <cookie>11</cookie>
    <idle-timeout>3400</idle-timeout>
    <flow-name>flowicmp1</flow-name>
    <priority>2</priority>
</flow>
```

and here the result that shown on the flow table:

```
{
    "flow-node-inventory:table": [
        {
            "id": 235,
            "opendaylight-flow-table-statistics:flow-table-statistics": {
                "active-flows": 3,
                "packets-looked-up": 0,
                "packets-matched": 0
            },
            "flow": [
                {
                    "id": "100",
                    "priority": 2,
                    "opendaylight-flow-statistics:flow-statistics": {
                        "packet-count": 0,
                        "byte-count": 0,
                        "duration": {
                            "nanosecond": 589000000,
                            "second": 12
                        }
                    },
                    "table_id": 235,
                    "cookie_mask": 0,
                    "hard-timeout": 1200,
                    "match": {
                        "ethernet-match": {
                            "ethernet-source": {
                                "address": "e8:06:88:xx:xx:xx"
                            },
                            "ethernet-type": {
                                "type": 2048
                            },
                            "ethernet-destination": {
                                "address": "e8:06:88:xx:xx:xx"
                            }
                        },
                        "icmpv4-match": {
                            "icmpv4-code": 3,
                            "icmpv4-type": 6
                        },
                        "ip-match": {
                            "ip-dscp": 27,
                            "ip-protocol": 1,
                            "ip-ecn": 3
                        },
                        "ipv4-destination": "192.168.5.100/32",
                        "ipv4-source": "192.168.1.100/32",
                        "in-port": "3"
                    },
                    "cookie": 11,
                    "flags": "",
                    "instructions": {
                        "instruction": [
                            {
                                "order": 0,
                                "apply-actions": {
                                    "action": [
                                        {
                                            "order": 0,
                                            "dec-nw-ttl": {}
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "idle-timeout": 3400
                },
```

What did i do wrong? i expect the hosts to be able to ping each other after i made that flow push.

Answer (score 0):

the action of your flow seems to be to just decrement the ttl. do you want
the action to be to forward out of another port?

also, is the output you gave for the flow table coming from the config
datastore or operational? if you add a flow (e.g. via REST) it will end
up in the config datastore. However, if the flow never gets programmed
on the openflow switch it will not end up in the operational datastore. The
operational datastore reflects the actual state of the network, whereas the
config datastore reflects the "desired" state.

Comment: i want the flow to accept icmp packet and forward it to another port, i use the xml that i got from the documentation guide site and change it to my need but the result is negative. 

and the result of the flow table that i shown above is from the operational, not from config.